# Bert fine-tuned for semantic similarity

Tags: nlp, cosine-similarity, pearson-correlation, sentence-similarity

I would like to apply fine-tuning Bert to calculate semantic similarity between sentences.
I search a lot websites, but I almost not found downstream about this.

I just found **STS benchmark**.
I wonder if I can use STS benchmark dataset to train a fine-tuning bert model, and apply it to my task. 
Is it reasonable?

As I know, there are a lot method to calculate similarity including cosine similarity, pearson correlation, manhattan distance, etc.
How choose for semantic similarity?

Comment: check this package https://pypi.org/project/similar-sentences/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a [rather popular paper in the field](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/view/12195/12023) by Mueller and Thyagarajan, which is concerned with learning sentence similarity on LSTMs, they use a closely related dataset (the [SICK dataset](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2014/task1/)), which is also hosted by the SemEval competition, and ran alongside the STS benchmark in 2014.

Either one of those should be a reasonable set to fine-tune on, but STS has run over multiple years, so the amount of available training data might be larger.

As a great primer on the topic, I can also highly recommend the Medium article by Adrien Sieg (see [here](https://medium.com/@adriensieg/text-similarities-da019229c894), which comes with an accompanied GitHub reference.

For semantic similarity, I would estimate that you are better of with fine-tuning (or training) a neural network, as most classical similarity measures you mentioned have a more prominent focus on the token similarity (and thus, syntactic similarity, although not even that necessarily). Semantic meaning, on the other hand, can sometimes differ wildly on a single word (maybe a negation, or the swapped sentence position of two words), which is difficult to interpret or evaluate with static methods.

Comment: Thank for your help.
I am not familiar with this platform.
I will check "ask" rules again.

Comment: My bad, formatting got caught up with me here. I'll extend the formatting ASAP

Comment: check this dataset paper, a tuned Bert for semantic similarity arxiv.org/abs/2004.10349

Answer (score 2):

In addition, if you're after a binary verdict (yes/no for 'semantically similar'), BERT was actually benchmarked on this task, using the MRPC (Microsoft Research Paraphrase Corpus).
The google github repo https://github.com/google-research/bert includes some example calls for this, see --task_name=MRPC in section Sentence (and sentence-pair) classification tasks.

Comment: HuggingFace has example and fine-tuned BERT on MRPC here - https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thank for your advice. I know that, but my mission isn't binary. My mission is that I have 100,00 questions and 300 different items' description. I would like to match a item for every question.